# While publishing SOAP with Attachment, where attachment is of size greater than 10 MB. Socket Exception as connection reset by peer on Wildfly 10.1

Tags: sockets, soap, wildfly

I have deployed my application on Wildfly 10.1.0 Final. I create a SOAP Message with Attachment and publish that SOAP Message. The attachment is stored in database and it is fetched before SOAP Message is published. The SOAP Message is successfully published if the attachment size is less than 10 MB.

When the attachment size is greater than 10 MB following exception occurs:

```
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
361 
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
362 
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111)
363 
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155)
364 
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:431)
365 
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:417)
366 
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:876)
367 
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:847)
368 
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123)
369 
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.streamWrite(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:126)
370 
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionOutputBufferImpl.write(SessionOutputBufferImpl.java:162)
371 
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedOutputStream.flushCacheWithAppend(ChunkedOutputStream.java:124)
372 
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedOutputStream.write(ChunkedOutputStream.java:181)
373 
    at org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity.writeTo(ByteArrayEntity.java:116)
374 
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:158)
375 
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:162)
376 
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:237)
377 
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122)
378 
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
379 
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
380 
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
381 
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
382 
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
383 
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
384 
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
385 
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
```

This issue does not occur on other application servers. Is this issue WildFly specific? Is there any troubleshoot in WildFly configuration?

Comment: What is consuming the SOAP message?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found the problem. It was configuration changes required to handle large attachments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. I needed to tweak WildFly configuration for http listener. I changed values of max-post-size and max-header-size to suit my large soap attachments.